# Input-form on select not working | materialize

Tags: css, class, select, input, materialize

Anybody knows why the materialize select It’s not working if has the input-field class? I’m using the last materialize version(0.100.2). I’m also adding all the requiered files(css,js,jquery). It works if use the "browser-default" class but not with the "input-field". Any idea of why it’s not working? Help.

It should work like this, but it is not:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
 </div>
```

Only works like this, and looks bad:

```
<label>Browser Select</label>
<select class="browser-default">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your post, e.g. a code snippet which reproduces your problem.

Comment: I modified it, thanks. (I'm new in this site)